# Can you save the civilians in Chapter 11 from the bandits?

Tags: metro-last-light

In Chapter 11 there is a group of metronian's who's forward segment was captured by bandits. The first group of bandits you come across are about to have forced sexual relations with a resisting woman. Can you save her before they kill or knock her out? That goes for other people that they have captured. If I move fast enough, can I save them from the bandits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes **you can save the first woman**, I was wondering the same thing so I restarted the checkpoint and did it faster. I managed to save her but she said nothing, just sat there weeping.

Later on I managed to save the woman with kids (which is probably scened and had to happen).

Other than that I haven't found more civilians, feel free to expand.

Comment: I haven't completed this chapter but I noticed in the next area, this is a bandit executing some of the men. I was hoping I could be able to stealth my way fast through this part and save them.

Comment: Yes that thought occurred to me too,but when playing I was moving the whole time(through the ducts),just took a quick look at the hostages...By the time I exited the ducts they executed them.I could have been a bit faster,but It didn't seem possible so I haven't tried it again.

Comment: If you mean the sick men at a station you see through a vent grill, you can get there before they finish off the last one, he will give you some information and die.

Comment: @kotekzot I am not sure that we are talking about the same part. I am talking about the chapter where you find a group of refugees whose forward section was killed or captured by bandits.

Comment: @Draedalus likely, I was replying to Arremer.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that you can save all of the people who are left. As Arremer explained, you can save the first by going quickly and she will just sit there and cry (as she would cause her situation sucks).

As for the two further down the tunnel:

> They can be saved if you kill all the enemies fast enough (I did it with stealth so I can't speak to other methods). The one who gets shot first if you don't save them, runs off into the death trap that is radiation after his executioner is killed. The other moves the train car out of your way, once you free him. He may not die if you don't get there in time for the first, I just never got there so I am not sure.

Comment: I think those 2 guys will survive regardless, otherwise you wouldn't be able to ride Regina farther.

Comment: Well I know the first one can get killed, as I played through once without going fast, and he is executed before the bandit moves on to the second guy.

Answer (score 0):

I played this level 10 times and concluded that you can save the first woman if you reach there before the bandits kill her. But regarding the other two guys who are being executed, no matter what, you can save only one of them. The other guy gets killed in every scenario. I tried to approach them while they were talking and took out the executioner with a sniper, the other bandit turned towards me and started screaming and the hostage started running and fell dead to the floor in a matter of seconds without getting hit.